# Bash interactive shell hangs when Tmux is suspended if it was automatically started by Bash startup file

Tags: bash, tmux, job-control

When I manually start *Tmux* by issuing `tmux` from my Bash interactive shell I can later suspend *Tmux* with <kbd>CTRL-BZ</kbd> without problems. Pressing this key combination brings me back to the parent process, i.e. the Bash interactive shell from which I started *Tmux*.

But I've got the following code snippet at the very end of my configuration file for *Bash* interactive shells (`~/.bashrc`) defined:

```
# Test if neither _Tmux_ nor _Screen_ is running.
if ! [[ -n "$TMUX" || "$TERM" =~ screen ]]; then
  # Test if _Tmux_ is on the `$PATH`.
  if type -p tmux &> /dev/null; then
    # Try to attach to latest unattached session or start a new one.
    { tmux attach-session || tmux new-session; } &> /dev/null
  fi
fi
```

This code snippet automatically starts *Tmux* whenever I start a *Bash* interactive shell given that there no terminal multiplexer program running yet.

But pressing <kbd>CTRL-BZ</kbd> this time around suspends *Tmux* leaving me in an unresponsive parent process, i.e. the Bash interactive shell that automatically started *Tmux* from its startup file (`~/.bashrc`).

Apart from detaching *Tmux* from and reattaching it to a session, is there a way to make *Tmux* suspend in such a way that I can continue to work in its parent *Bash* interactive shell and come back later foregrounding it with `fg`?

Please note that for various reasons I intend to let *Bash* fork *Tmux* and and not replace itself by it (`exec`).

Comment: I wonder if nulling stdout & stderr is related, does removing the `&> /dev/null` change anything? Didn't seem to change anything when testing for me

Comment: No it does not. I tried that already. I deliberately silenced the commands in order to not be bothered with messages such as `no sessions` and `[exited]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn job control on with `set -m` in your `.bashrc` before starting `tmux`.

Bash runs startup files like `.bashrc` with job control disabled. From [shell.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=d894cfd10#n1117):

```c
#if defined (JOB_CONTROL)
  /* Startup files should be run without job control enabled. */
  old_job_control = interactive_shell ? set_job_control (0) : 0;
#endif
```

Please notice that `C-b C-z` does not set tmux in the background by itself; **absent job control** in the upper shell, the `SIGTSTP` signal tmux sends itself will just cause it to stop; the `tmux` process will *still* be in the foreground process group of the terminal (despite the deceptive switching from the alternate screen with the the `exit_ca_mode`/`rmcup`/`te` escape on some terminal emulators like `xterm`)