# gnome-terminal - Execute command with ability to suspend

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have an application launcher that executes a command inside gnome-terminal with the -- option, but whenever I go into the terminal and try crtl-z to try to suspend the command and move it to the background nothing happens. My search found a bunch of posts about launching interactive shells in bash, but nothing I've tried there works either. Is there way to launch gnome-terminal and execute a command that gives me the ability to suspend the command and bring up a prompt later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash_in_gnome_terminal(){
    local IFS
    printf -v cmd %q ". ~/.bashrc; set -m; $*"
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo $cmd)"
}

bash_in_gnome_terminal tail -f ~/.xsession-errors
bash_in_gnome_terminal 'grep -r pattern dir | less'
```

This solution is complicated (and crippled!) by the fact that the `gnome-terminal` command actually calls into a "terminal server" to spawn a terminal instance, and you cannot pass file descriptors to the process running in it.

With other terminals like `xterm` or `mlterm` the solution is simpler and more functional:

```
bash_in_xterm(){
    local IFS
    xterm -e bash --rcfile <(printf '. ~/.bashrc; set -m; %s\n' "$*")
}
```

Also, it would be nice if bash had an option to run some commands before an interactive shell (like `vi +'cmd'`), without a kludge like `--rcfile <(...)`. Maybe it even has -- but I wasn't able to figure it out ;-)

The `set -m` is needed because bash sources the initialization files with the [monitor mode off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476870/308316), ie without job control and the possibility of using `^Z`, `fg`, `bg`, etc.

---

If you want the shell to exit and the terminal to close when the started command has exited, the function could be modified like this [assumes a recent version of bash]:

```
bash_in_gnome_terminal(){
    local IFS
    set -- 'sigchld(){ local j="\j"; ((${j@P})) || exit; }; trap sigchld CHLD;' "$@"
    printf -v cmd %q ". ~/.bashrc; set -m; $*"
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo $cmd)"
}
```

The `${var@P}` form expands any prompt escapes in `var`, and the `\j` prompt escape expands to the number of jobs. Thence `j="\j"; ((${j@P})) || exit` as called from the `CHLD` trap will exit the shell if there are no more jobs.

In older version of bash which do not support the `${var@P}` expansion form, a  clunkier kludge will have to be used:

```
set -- 'sigchld(){ trap - CHLD; test "$(jobs -p)" || exit; trap sigchld CHLD; }; trap sigchld CHLD;' "$@"
```

Here the `CHLD` trap has to be disabled and then reenabled, otherwise the `$(jobs -p)` command substitution will trigger it recursively.

---

This whole thing could be made into a standalone script instead of a function:

```
#! /bin/bash

# uncomment and edit the following line accordingly
# set -- <fixed command and arguments> "$@"

# this only works in bash >= 4.4
# set -- 'sigchld(){ local j="\j"; ((${j@P})) || exit; }; trap sigchld CHLD;' "$@"
set -- 'sigchld(){ trap - CHLD; test "$(jobs -p)" || exit; trap sigchld CHLD; }; trap sigchld CHLD;' "$@"

printf -v cmd %q ". ~/.bashrc; set -m; $*"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo $cmd)"
```

Comment: I created a script with your gnome-terminal answer, modified to call my commands from the function at the end. This pretty much did what I wanted, with the only downside being that the terminal doesn't close when I exit the command like the old gnome-terminal launcher did. But still a great improvement!

Comment: @wile_e8 see the updated function / script at the end of the answer

Comment: I tried the updated script (both versions), but kept getting the same errors at the end instead of exiting:

~~~
    bash: ${j@P}: bad substitution
~~~

This would appear 2-3 times after I exited instead of the terminal closing, and then if I ran any commands in the terminal it would appear 2-3 times after each of those commands.

Comment: @wile_e8 that form of variable expansion is only present in newer versions of bash (>= 4.4 or so). I'll add a workaround -- which would be quite clunky, unfortunately.

Comment: @wile_e8 see the added workaround. I had included it in the external script variant by default.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!