# Command/script to start a terminal, enter text but don't execute (wait for text to be written, pasted, etc.)

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, terminal

I often

1. write commands in the terminal that I don't know by heart, and then
2. paste some path or file name from the clipboard, before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I thought that it would be fun to **do the first part with one shortcut** and then just paste, achieving the above with key actions.

---

Based on [this answer under "How to assign a certain keyboard shortcut to paste specific item?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/793934/925128), I have added to a shortcut `bash -c "xsel -ib <<< 'MY_COMMAND'"`, which sends a command to the clipboard. But, when pasting that in the terminal, the command is automatically executed, because an "Enter" (newline) is present at the end:

[image: displaying clipboard after executing "xsel -ib <<< 'MY_COMMAND' "]

---

[This is in Kubuntu 20.04.]

Comment: The thing you see at the end is definitely not a "space", it's a "Enter" (aka "newline" or `\n`). That's the symbol I see when I do <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> with `libreoffice`. A space at the end of a command will never make a `bash` command to execute. Also, I'm not sure I really understood your problem : do you **only** want to prevent `bash` from executing **any** text you pasted ? Or do you want something more ?

Comment: @ewen-goisot - answered under you answer.

Comment: FYI, bash automatically appends a newline to a "here string".  See [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION): "The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command on its standard input".  Try ``printf '%s' 'MY_COMMAND' | xsel -ib`` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer to "How to avoid xsel sending text to clipboard with space/Enter at the end"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644142/341192) I now have a workaround. I don't know how to start the terminal with a text therein waiting for a new input (typed, pasted), **with one action** (script/command/shortcut) but now I can do it in *two* steps:

1. Use a shortcut associated with the `bash -c 'printf "%s" "MY_TEXT" | xsel -b' ; konsole` to send that text to clipboard and open a terminal like `konsole`
2. Ctrl-V to paste text from clipboard to terminal (or Ctrl-Shift-V)

(These two keyboard actions achieve what in the initial question is point no 1. An example of how that can be useful is that of downloading audio from youtube: (#1) `bash -c 'printf "%s" "youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a]" | xsel -b' && konsole` copies to clipboard the necessary command and opens a terminal where (#2) it can be pasted, thus putting forth a window for you to add the youtube link with another (#3)copy+(#4)paste -- or maybe just *one* drag & drop (that's #3), followed by (#4/5) Enter. A total of 4 or 5 keyboard & mouse actions without the need for actually writing anything.)

I would love to have that with one command but I think this fits here as a complementary answer anyway (rather than within the question body).

Comment: When you say `2. Ctrl-V to paste text from clipboard to terminal` you probably mean `Ctrl-Shift-V` instead of `Ctrl-V` if you want to paste with a terminal. (I tried with `konsole` too and `Ctrl-V` does nothing like paste).

Comment: @ewen-goisot - True. I will edit. I'm one of those that change Ctrtl-Shift to Ctrl for copy/paste early after installing the OS. Right click on the menu option to edit it in Konsole.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I also changed some shortcuts, and my current paste shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl '</kbd> (control + single quote), and also have the <kbd>Ctrl+Insert</kbd> shortcut when my keyboard is in "mouse mode". What is written right now is clear enough : you put both, so, other users who didn't configured anything will still understand. Note: I use <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-l</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl-l</kbd> to clear the console (and the other is for `lf` file manager). I may accidentaly write the wrong one on my answer; (now it's corrected, issue will be only if I edit again).

Answer (score 1):

## How to start a terminal with text typed inside ?

### Run a command in a terminal :

Typing a text or execute a command in a terminal are quite similar. First, let us see how we can open a terminal executing a command.

To execute a command, you can do `konsole -e MY_COMMAND`.
Of course, this is not what you want, but it will help.
I first need to say that there is no official option for that in `konsole` or any terminal I have seen, but we can make one… based on `konsole -e` feature.
Currently, I know only how to do it with `gnome-terminal` and with `konsole`, and there is probably a similar way to do it with other terminal emulators.

By making several tests, I noticed a big issue : `konsole -e` stops after the execution of the command : `konsole -e sleep 10` will display a `konsole` terminal during 10 seconds, with no ability to run a shell command, and then it closes itself.
But I need the `konsole` terminal to stay open if I want to perform some actions inside it.
Why is it like that? I think it can make sense in some contexts, like `konsole -e top` (task manager) or `konsole -e vim` (text editor), and quit `konsole` when you quit `vim` (then, this `vim` behaves like a GUI text editor that you can close, like `gedit`).
I got the same issue with `st -e MY_COMMAND` or `gnome-terminal -- MY_COMMAND`.
So I saw [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575173/gnome-terminal-execute-command-with-ability-to-suspend) and it exactly solves the issue (except it's made only for `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`, so there may or may not be a similar solution for `konsole`).

First, let's create a function to run `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` that does not quit after executing something:

```
bash_in_gnome_terminal(){
    local IFS
    printf -v cmd %q ". ~/.bashrc; set -m; $*"
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo $cmd)"
}

bash_in_konsole(){
    local IFS
    konsole -e bash --rcfile <(printf '. ~/.bashrc; set -m; %s\n' "$*")
}
```

You can test it with `bash_in_konsole 'echo foo'` and you are supposed to see something like:

```
foo
username@computer:~$
```

### Type text with `tmux` :

I was first thinking about `xdotool` to type text, but it will be some issues if the `konsole` window isn't focused.
Usually, `tmux` isn't pre-installed. On a Debian-based distro, the command to install it is `sudo apt-get install tmux`.
Actually, `tmux` has a `send-keys` feature. Of course, if it's with `tmux`, you should run a `tmux` session. Maybe you will need to install `tmux` first.
Try this if you want to understand how this works :

- `tmux` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (launched the session).
- <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> (enter in command mode).
- `send-keys "echo foo"`<kbd>Enter</kbd> (type it as if you typed it), you are supposed to see something like:

  username@computer:~$ echo foo

Now, you can merge the two parts :
`bash_in_konsole 'exec tmux new-session -A -t "temporary" \; run-shell "sleep .1" \; send-keys "C-u" "echo foo" "C-l"'`.
I will explain :

- `exec` leaves the terminal when you leave `tmux`, you quit `konsole`.
- `new-session -A -t "temporary"` launches the same session if you used the command before, but then, the sessions will be numbered with huge numbers.
- `send-keys "echo foo"` will type `echo foo` in the terminal.
  Unfortunatly, it will be written twice (once before the shell prompt and once inside it).
- `"C-u"` will clear the line (necessary if you use the `-A -t "temporary"` arguments).
- `"C-l"` is sent it as keys too, <kbd>Ctrl-l</kbd> is the official `bash` shortcut to clear the screen
  (avoids to see twice the `echo foo`).
  **Note** : <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-l</kbd> also works on some shells. Maybe not on `bash`.
- It will not echo `foo` alone, until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. You can also modify the command `echo foo` to anything you want.

### Clipboard without the "Enter" (newline) at the end:

If you copied the URL `http://youtube.com/foobar`, the output of `xsel -ob` contains a trailing newline `\n` (the same char you usually get when you press Enter). Depending on the context, there are several things you can do :

- To get only the first line without a trailing space : `xsel -ob | head -1 | tr -d "\n"`
- To put spaces instead of newlines : `xsel -ob | tr "\n" " "`.
  **why a space** and not "nothing"? Because you may have copied several URL (several lines) and `youtube-dl` can download a space-separated set of videos.

**warning:** : in your case, you are using `youtube-dl`, and YouTube's URL may include timestamp like `http://youtube.com/foobar&t=21m17s` meaning the video will automatically start at `21:17` when you launch it in web browser. Also, for some reason, timestamps may appear automatically. And the ampersand `&` is the `bash` command to do a fork. It means it will be difficult to calcel it with <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> if you accidently pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You may also want to escape the characters that are both usually escaped and presents in YouTube's URL, like `?` and `=`, but for `zsh` (and maybe some other shells) users only : using `zsh`, the `?` causes a `no matches found` error message.

- `bash`, To escape the ampersand only : `xsel -ob | tr "\n" " " | sed "s/&/\\\\&/g"`.
- `zsh` , To escape the 3 problematic symbols : `xsel -ob | tr "\n" " " | sed "s/\(?\|=\|&\)/\\\\\1/g"`.
  **note:** most of time, I assume the reader is a `bash` user, but I personally use `zsh`, so most commands are supposed to work with `zsh` too. If you face an issue with another shell, please, let me know.

### Official solution, (merge of the 3 previous parts) :

**Step 0 :** I assume the reader wants to do this with `bash`, `konsole` and a `youtube-dl` command, and the typed command should include clipboard content. I also assume this is for a shortcut made in `konsole` (for other readers who will simply run it in terminal, make sure you reload your `~/.bashrc` after editing it).

**Step 1 :** Install `tmux` if you don't have it.

**Step 2 :** Copy the 7 following lines and paste it to your `~/.bashrc` file (and save the file) :

```
bash_in_konsole(){
    local IFS
    konsole -e bash --rcfile <(printf '. ~/.bashrc; set -m; %s\n' "$*")
}

tmux_in_konsole(){
    bash_in_konsole 'exec tmux new-session -A -t "temporary" \; run-shell "sleep .1" \; send-keys "C-u" "' "$*" '" "C-l"'
}
```

**Step 3 :** Now, you can test with `tmux_in_konsole "youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] $(xsel -ob | tr "\n" " " | sed "s/&/\\\\&/g")"`. This is the command you should put for your `konsole` shortcut. Let's say you copied the URL `http://youtube.com/watch?v=foobarlorem&t=10s`. The expected result is:

```
username@computer:~$ youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] http://youtube.com/watch?v=foobarlorem\&t=10s
```

**Step 3 bis :** (alternative to 3) If you don't want the clipboard content to be pasted, it's simpler. You can test with `tmux_in_konsole "youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] "`. The expected result is:

```
username@computer:~$ youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a]
```

**[Step ω :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number)** (when you quit `konsole`) Once you have typed the URL of the video you want to download with `youtube-dl`, and you typed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you finished to download the video, you can quit this terminal.
To quit `tmux`, simply press <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd><kbd>Shift-d</kbd> (you can also quit it the way you quit a shell, with <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>, but it means this `tmux` session will then be closed, and you will get huge numbers again).
If you accidentally closed `konsole` before the end of the download, `tmux` will allow it to run in the background. But don't do this purposely, because it may cause some problems (at least display-related) if you run a second instance of `tmux_in_konsole` while the first download didn't ended.

---

**Note**: I removed every other part of my comment because it is messy and I first misunderstood a part of your question.
I think there is still a way to see it by seeing the revisions history. I also keep a copy of it on my computer if needed.
**Note**: personal `zsh` shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-l</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl-l</kbd>, if you still see the first one, it's a pasting mistake from me. If you see this note, it could also be a pasting mistake from me ! (but this time, it wasn't)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122916/discussion-on-answer-by-ewen-goisot-command-script-to-start-a-terminal-enter-te).