# How to avoid xsel sending text to clipboard with space/Enter at the end

Tags: clipboard, xsel

I am trying to answer this other question: [Command/script to start a terminal, enter text but don't execute...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644117/341192). I want to start the terminal and add specific text to it **without executing**, thus allowing me to copy some other variable text to it before executing. It's like when pasting `sudo apt install mpv` into terminal without space at the end: the command will not start, but allow for example to add other programs to be installed.

I have come close to a solution with `xsel`, which can send a command to terminal with a shortcut.

The commands to be used can be something like

```
bash -c "xsel -ib <<< 'MY_TEXT'"
```

or

```
bash -c "xsel -p <<< 'MY_TEXT'"
```

Thus, I can send that text to clipboard with one shortcut, open terminal with another shortcut, then paste what `xsel` has copied to clipboard.

The problem is that the `xsel` command sends to clipboard the text with a space or Enter at the end

[image]

It's `MY_TEXT`  instead of `MY_TEXT`

It's like the difference between `sudo apt install mpv`  which automatically runs the installation command and `sudo apt install mpv` that waits for me to press enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here strings [have a newline appended to them](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings). If you avoid that, you won’t get a newline in the pasted text:

```
bash -c 'printf "%s" "MY_TEXT" | xsel -p'
```

Comment: I hope I'm not out of line here: could you tell me also if there's a possible answer to my linked question? Trying with `printf '%s' "MY_COMMAND" | xsel -p && konsole --hold -e xsel -p`  to get MY_COMMAND in terminal and wait for new input (like when pasting `sudo apt install mpv`), I get `MY_COMMAND
\ No newline at end of selection`: I would like to get just `MY_COMMAND` and be able to type/paste a path after that.

Comment: I don’t know (otherwise I’d [answer your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644117/86440) directly).

Comment: Meanwhile, you provided me with a 3-step workaround: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644155/341192).

Comment: Made that 2-step :)